# analyticsoverflow - tracking question and answer counts over time

Tags: app, ruby

[image]
[image]

### About

Question, answer and comment counts for stackoverflow. The individual tag pages show a graph of the question counts over the last fortnight.

*Update:* Now gathers and displays data for all 3 trilogy sites.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

http://popacular.com/analyticsoverflow/
http://github.com/reednj/stackoverflow-counter

#### Platform

MySql+Apache

### Contact

See github

### Code

It's written in ruby and running on mysql+apache. The code is not impressive, but it is [up on github](http://github.com/reednj/stackoverflow-counter). It was originally implemented a month or so ago using a screenscaper to get the data, and has recently been converted to use the api.

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate as many other StackApps apps as I can in my aggregator application and yours is a cool one I'd like to use. However, it only seems to support Stack Overflow. Any chance you can build in a paramter to change the API site?

Comment: Trilogy support is now added, just use the ?site= parameter..

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea.

It would be interesting to be able to compare languages over time, similar to  http://langpop.com/

You could also display the top (10) tags per day/week/month.

A search form for checking arbitrary tags would be nice too - you only link to a very small few. Bonus points for autocomplete.

Comment: You can searcb for any tag in the top 70 by changing the url. `/?tag=<tagname>`

Answer (score 2):

An API would be cool